# Need help determining the lowest and highest value within an algorithm using pseudocode

Tags: arrays, algorithm, pseudocode

I'm having a lot of trouble dealing with with a particular question in my critical thinking class.
The task is this:

**Task**

*Develop an algorithm to prompt for and obtain maximum daily temperatures for a whole year. However, in order to consider leap years, your algorithm should first prompt the user for the number of days in this particular year. That is, your algorithm should expect 365 or 366 as the first input number followed by input temperature values.*

*In addition, for this particular year, your algorithm must also determine and display the average, maximum, and minimum of these temperatures values.*

Here's an example of what needs to happen:
Prompt for number of days in a year 
(let's say they enter 365)

Then prompt user for MAXIMUM daily tempretures for 365 days.

Take those 365 (individual) maximum tempretures, find the lowest value that will = Min_temp.

Take those 365 (individual) maximum tempretures, find the highest value that will = Max_temp.

Sum up all 365 invidual max tempretures and divide it by the number of days in the year (365) = Avg_temp.

Print Min_temp

Print Max_temp

Print Avg_temp

So far this is what I have:

```
1.  Prompt operator to enter Number_Of_Days within year.
2.  WHILE Number_Of_Days = 365 or 366 THEN
3.      IF Number_Of_Days is = 365 THEN
4.          Year = 365
5.      ELSEIF Number_Of_Days = 366 THEN
6.          Year = 366
7.      ENDIF
8.  ELSEWHILE Number_of_Days is NOT = 365 or 366 THEN
9.      Print ‘ERROR: Please enter a number that is 365 or 366.’ 
10.     Prompt operator to enter Number_Of_Days within year.        
11. ENDWHILE
12. DOWHILE MaxDayTemp = 1 to Year
16.     Prompt operator for MaxDailyTemp
15. ENDO
```

From here we're meant to get an average of all the maximum temps provided by the user, that's easily done by AVG_TEMP = Sum of Temps / Days in the year.

What I can't work out is how to take the values of each day and find the lowest and highest values that are provided.
I've been trying to work it out with an array but I'm totally confused by it.

Please help! :(

Comment: why `WHILE Number_Of_Days = 365 or 366 THEN` btw? the `while` should be `if`, isn't it

Comment: That pseudocode language seems quite unusual.  Is that a given language or did you make it up?

Comment: Could you please write a more descriptive title for the question?

Comment: The pseudocode is meant to be simple English, the operators I'm using are in capitals. 

I used while instead of if because I wanted it to loop until either 365 or 366 was entered.

Comment: Okay I've written a more descriptive title for the question.

Comment: you've made that too complex, you could have written a simpler code, try my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are expecting something like this, tried to use your conversion. Format it as you want.

```
i=0;
tempsum=0;
tempmax=0;
tempmin=100;
currenttemp=0;
no_days=0;
// variables used to store values

do
    (prompt user for number of days)
    no_days = user input
while no_days!=365 or no_days!=366 // will loop until user enter 365 or 366

while i<no_days
    do
        (Prompt operator for MaxDailyTemp)
        currenttemp = userinput
    while (currenttemp value is invalid)    // thinking in the same way as above

    if currenttemp > tempmax
        tempmax = currenttemp
    else if currenttemp < tempmin
        tempmin = currenttemp
    tempsum = tempsum + currenttemp 
    i = i+1
end

display average temp. = tempsum/no_days
display max temp. = tempmax
display min temp. = tempmin
```

Comment: YES! YES! YES! 

Thank you so much Anubis! :D~

Comment: I'm so sorry if my question was hard to understand!

Comment: it's not about difficulty in your question, it's not a question at all. you should be able to solve that kind of problems. Trying to find solutions to that much simpler questions from other people wont do any good for your 'critical thinking'. you should learn to think..

Comment: Fair call, I am still learning and new to learning this kind of stuff, the pressure of all my other subjects as well as being new to it all left me with only a few days to finish an assignment. If I had more time I may have thought of a solution without asking, regardless I appreciate your assistance and understand what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what syntax is required for your class but this

```
max = (1 st value)
min = (1 st value)
i = 2
WHILE i < year THEN
    IF (i th value) > max THEN 
        max = (i th value)
    ELSIF (i th value) < min THEN
        min = (i th value)
    i = i + 1
```

would get the min and max value.

Comment: This was also very helpful, in essence that is what I as looking for, a way to determine the lowest and highest value within many values entered for each day of a year.

Comment: @Smash still you can give a +1 if you find an answer (or a comment) useful.

Comment: It says "Vote Up requires 15 reputation", else I would.